# MySQL replace into behavior with unique constraint

Tags: mysql, replace, constraints, unique

I have a quick question about MySQL behavior.

Imagine a table with 3(relevant) columns:

```
id (PK + AI),somedate,someuser,etc...
```

I have put a unique constraint on (date,user). So when I start with a clean test table and run the following query twice:

```
REPLACE INTO `testtable` (somedate,someuser) VALUES('2017-01-01','admin');
```

I expected a row with the 'id' column on 1. but instead everytime I run this query the id goes up because of the auto increment and I can't have that happen (this would corrupt my data relations). Why is this? Can I make it so that I can keep the original primary key when a replace into occurs?

Comment: Show the REAL schema for this table

Comment: Why not use `update` ?

Comment: @PrabhatG Because I wanted it quick and dirty ;) In all seriousness: I just stumbled upon the behavior and I wanted to better understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with the `REPLACE`. That's like an `INSERT` preceded by a `DELETE`. The behavior you observe with `REPLACE` is the same as the behavior you would see if you executed these two statements:

```
 DELETE FROM `testtable` WHERE somedate = '2017-01-01' and someuser = 'admin';
 INSERT INTO `testtable` (somedate,someuser) VALUES ('2017-01-01','admin');
```

And that means the auto_increment column on the newly inserted row will have a new value.

---

Perhaps consider using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

(Note that the attempt to insert a row that gets updated will use an auto_increment value.)

Answer (score 0):

To me looks like you actually wanted an `UPDATE` statement rather like

```
update `testtable` 
set somedate = '2017-01-01',
    someuser = 'admin'
where id = <id of the record> ;
```